# Building totals based on condition in another row

Tags: t-sql, pivot

Really struggling to understand the best way of doing this...

I have a table of data

```
**StudentID  AssessmentCode  ResultGroup    Result**
  46933          12ENG        IBLevel          HL
  46933          12ENG        Mark             6
  46933          12ECO        IBLevel          HL
  46933          12ECO        Mark             5
  46933          12GEO        IBLevel          SL
  46933          12GEO        Mark             6
  46933          12LAN        IBLevel          HL
  46933          12LAN        Mark             4
  46933          12PED        IBLevel          SL
  46933          12PED        Mark             5
  46933          12SCI        IBLevel          SL
  46933          12SCI        Mark             3
  67767          12FRE        IBLevel          HL
  67767          12FRE        Mark             4
  67767          12MAT        IBLevel          SL
  67767          12MAT        Mark             5
  and so on...
```

Unfortunately the result column holds 2 different bits of info. The level a student does (HL = High Level; SL = Standard Level) and then the result for that subject at that level. Note that for each student, 2 rows are generated per subject a student does, one row has the IBLevel and the next row has the result for that level.

How can I rearrange the data to get something like

```
StudentID    HLResult    SLResult    TotalResult   CountofHL  CountofSL
  46933         15          14           29            3          3
  67767         13          10           23            4          2
```

So each student has one row of data with totals for HL, SL, both together and then a count of the number of HL and SL subjects. As I said, really not sure of the best way of going about this. In the end, I would also like to extend this to get some columns which, based on the results give some warning messages eg the TotalResult has to be great than 24 so I would love a column that simply returns whether this has been achieved or not...

```
StudentID  HLResult  SLResult  TotalResult CountofHL CountofSL MoreThan24
  46933       15        14         29          3        3         True
  67767       13        10         23          4        2         False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: How do you know which mark goes with which level? Your table is in serious need of normalization.

Comment: Yeah - the table is not mine. It is the table that stores all the results for our student database from commercial software we use. As you say, it is painful to work with due to the way it sets up this table. The result column stores ALL results, from marks to grades, to strings to whatever. I have created quite a few views which pivot the data in order to normalize it. I will have a look at your code and get back to you. Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table seems to have some serious normalization issues. You have to perform an `INNER JOIN` on `AssessmentCode` first:

```
SELECT t1.StudentID, t1.AssessmentCode, 
       t1.Result AS Level, CAST(t2.Result AS INT) AS Mark 
FROM (
   SELECT StudentID, AssessmentCode, Result
   FROM mytable
   WHERE ResultGroup = 'IBLevel' ) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT StudentID, AssessmentCode, Result
   FROM mytable
   WHERE ResultGroup = 'Mark' ) AS t2
ON t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID AND t1.AssessmentCode = t2.AssessmentCode
```

to get one row per `AssessmentCode`.

**Output:**

```
StudentID   AssessmentCode  Level   Mark
-----------------------------------------
46933       12ENG           HL      6
46933       12ECO           HL      5
46933       12GEO           SL      6
46933       12LAN           HL      4
46933       12PED           SL      5
46933       12SCI           SL      3
67767       12FRE           HL      4
67767       12MAT           SL      5
```

You can now wrap the above query in a `CTE` and perform *conditional aggregation* to get required result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
 ... above query here
)
SELECT StudentID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 'HL' THEN Mark ELSE 0 END) AS HLResult,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 'SL' THEN Mark ELSE 0 END) AS SLResult,
       SUM(Mark) AS TotalResult,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Level = 'HL' THEN 1 END) AS CountofHL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Level = 'SL' THEN 1 END) AS CountofSL,
       CASE WHEN SUM(Mark) > 24 THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
       END AS MoreThan24
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StudentID
```

**Output:**

```
StudentID   HLResult    SLResult    TotalResult CountofHL   CountofSL   MoreThan24
46933       15          14          29          3           3           True
67767       4           5           9           1           1           False
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/633bb/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I normalized the table as you suggested above by joining the two views. Thanks also for the idea of using the CTE so you can  use SUM and Count. It all works well now.

Comment: Just to be clear, what I propose is not normalisation. It's rather a work around due to lack of a normalised table structure.

Answer (score 0):

### My Version of Your Table

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE
(
    StudentID       INT,
    AssessmentCode  CHAR(5),
    ResultGroup     VARCHAR(10),
    Result          VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (46933,'12ENG','IBLevel','HL'),
        (46933,'12ENG','Mark','6'),
        (46933,'12ECO','IBLevel','HL'),
        (46933,'12ECO','Mark','5'),
        (46933,'12GEO','IBLevel','SL'),
        (46933,'12GEO','Mark','6'),
        (46933,'12LAN','IBLevel','HL'),
        (46933,'12LAN','Mark','4'),
        (46933,'12PED','IBLevel','SL'),
        (46933,'12PED','Mark','5'),
        (46933,'12SCI','IBLevel','SL'),
        (46933,'12SCI','Mark','3'),
        (67767,'12FRE','IBLevel','HL'),
        (67767,'12FRE','Mark','4'),
        (67767,'12MAT','IBLevel','SL'),
        (67767,'12MAT','Mark','5');
```

### Actual Query

```
WITH CTE_ResultValue
AS
(
    SELECT  StudentID,
            AssessmentCode,
            ResultGroup,
            CAST(Result AS INT) AS ResultValue
    FROM @yourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Result) = 1
),
CTE_IBLevel
AS
(
    SELECT  StudentID,
        AssessmentCode,
        Result AS IBLevel
    FROM @yourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Result) = 0
),
CTE_Normalized
AS
(
    SELECT  A.StudentID,
            A.AssessmentCode,
            A.ResultGroup,
            A.ResultValue,
            B.IBLevel
    FROM CTE_ResultValue    AS A
    INNER JOIN CTE_IBLevel  AS B
    ON      A.StudentID = B.StudentID
        AND A.AssessmentCode = B.AssessmentCode
)

SELECT  [StudentID],
        [HLResult]      = SUM(CASE WHEN IBLevel = 'HL' THEN ResultValue END),
        [SLResult]      = SUM(CASE WHEN IBLevel = 'SL' THEN ResultValue END),
        [TotalResult]   = SUM(ResultValue),
        [CountOfHL]     = SUM(CASE WHEN IBLevel = 'HL' THEN 1 END),
        [CountOfSL]     = SUM(CASE WHEN IBLevel = 'SL' THEN 1 END)
FROM CTE_Normalized
GROUP BY StudentID
```

### Normalization

Your table is in serious need of normalization. If you can change it, bare minimal change would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NormalizedTable
(
    StudentID       INT,
    AssessmentCode  CHAR(5),
    ResultGroup     VARCHAR(25),
    ResultValue     SMALLINT, --smallint range should be plenty. It can store values from -32,768 to 32,767
    IBLevel         CHAR(2)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.NormalizedTable
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Normalized
```

If you can't change the way your data is structured, I'd recommend creating a view from my CTE_normalized

```
CREATE VIEW vw_normalizedTable
AS
WITH CTE_ResultValue
AS
(
    SELECT  StudentID,
            AssessmentCode,
            ResultGroup,
            CAST(Result AS INT) AS ResultValue
    FROM @yourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Result) = 1
),
CTE_IBLevel
AS
(
    SELECT  StudentID,
        AssessmentCode,
        Result AS IBLevel
    FROM @yourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Result) = 0
),

SELECT  A.StudentID,
        A.AssessmentCode,
        A.ResultGroup,
        A.ResultValue,
        B.IBLevel
FROM CTE_ResultValue    AS A
INNER JOIN CTE_IBLevel  AS B
ON      A.StudentID = B.StudentID
    AND A.AssessmentCode = B.AssessmentCode
GO
```

Comment: Yeah - the table is not mine. It is the table that stores all the results for our student database from commercial software we use. As you say, it is painful to work with due to the way it sets up this table. The result column stores ALL results, from marks to grades, to strings to whatever. I have created quite a few views which pivot the data in order to normalize it. I will have a look at your code and get back to you. Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

**Version1:**

```
SELECT t1.StudentID, 
SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'HL' THEN t2.Result ELSE 0 END) HLResult,
SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'SL' THEN t2.Result ELSE 0 END) SLResult,
SUM(CAST(t2.Result AS INT)) TotalResult,
SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'HL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountofHL,
SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'SL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountofSL,
CASE WHEN SUM(CAST(t2.Result AS INT)) > 24 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END MoreThan24    
FROM @t t1
JOIN @t t2 ON t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID AND 
              t1.AssessmentCode = t2.AssessmentCode AND 
              t1.ResultGroup = 'IBLevel' AND 
              t2.ResultGroup = 'Mark'
GROUP BY t1.StudentID
```

**Version2:**

```
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID, AssessmentCode 
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN ResultGroup = 'IBLevel' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS rn FROM @t),
cte2 AS(SELECT StudentID, 
               AssessmentCode, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'HL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) HL, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'SL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SL, 
               MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Result END) R
        FROM cte1
        GROUP BY StudentID, AssessmentCode)
SELECT StudentID, 
       SUM(hl*R) HLResult, 
       SUM(sl*R) SLResult, 
       SUM((hl + sl)*r) TotalResult, 
       SUM(hl) CountofHL, 
       SUM(sl) CountofSL,
       CASE WHEN SUM((hl + sl)*r) > 24 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END MoreThan24    
FROM cte2
GROUP BY StudentID
```

Output:

```
StudentID   HLResult    SLResult    TotalResult CountofHL   CountofSL   MoreThan24
46933       15          14          29          3           3           True
67767       4           5           9           1           1           False
```

Just replace `@t` with your table.